# Validating insert codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, mysqli

I'm trying to validating my insert data in codeigniter

The problem is the code returning me a duplicate entry's page error. And i want to throw that failure to home page with error message.

Here is my code:

```
$data = array(
            'heheId'   => $this->input->post('heheId'),
            'userId'  => $this->input->post('userId')
        );
    $this->db->insert('tentarasaya',$data);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('info', "Hore sukses");
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('danger', "Fail insert");
    }
    redirect('my_home');
```

Any answer?

Update:
Duplicate entry like this

[image]

Comment: For duplicate entry use unique validation `$this->form_validation->set_rules('field_name', 'Field', 'trim|required|is_unique[TABLENAME.COLUMNNAME]');
`

Comment: this is foreign key issue

Comment: and you have set this to **Unique** in your database. ***Remove it***

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$data = array(
    'heheId'   => $this->input->post('heheId'),
    'userId'  => $this->input->post('userId')
);  
if (!$this->db->insert('tentarasaya',$data)) { # add if here
    # Unsuccessful
    $this->session->set_flashdata('danger', "Fail insert");
}
else{
     # Success
    $this->session->set_flashdata('info', "Hore sukses");
}
redirect('my_home');
```

Comment: Not working, i'm still stuck on duplicate entry's page

Comment: duplicate entry page means??

Comment: @Andhika check     [Stays comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471990/validating-insert-codeigniter#comment56685328_34471990)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that auto increment option is selected in your database. I am assuming that user_id here is a primary key, no need to insert that into a database yourself.

```
 data = array(
            'heheId'   => $this->input->post('heheId'),
        );
    $this->db->insert('tentarasaya',$data);
```

Otherwise if you wish to insert user_ids yourself you can 1) define a custom call back function to check to see if the specified user id already exists in the database, 2) use the is_unique form validation rule that comes bundled with codeigniter